# Streaming dash video with flowplayer

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, audio-streaming, flowplayer, mpeg-dash

Suppose i have a direct link for video ( Dash only) and a separate link for audio , how can i stream the video with audio with flowplayer ? .For e.g youtube separate audio and video for 1080p and 480p.